# pandas - Process a column with alternating occurrences of two values with random frequencies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column as shown in the figure below. Only two values: `Increase` and `Decrease` occur randomly in the column. Is there a way to process that data?

[image]

For this particular problem, I want to get the first (2 CONSECUTIVE) occurrence of the word `Increase` AFTER at least one (2 CONSECUTIVE) occurrences (maybe more, 2 is the minimum) of the word `Decrease`.

As an example, if the series is (I for "Increase", D for "Decrease"): "`I,I,I,I,D,I,I,D,I,D,I,D,D,D,D,I,D,I,D,D,I,I,I,I`", it should return the index of row 21 (the third last `I` in the given series). Assume that the example series that I just showed in a pandas column, meaning the series is vertical and not horizontal, and the indexing starts at 0, meaning that the first `I` is considered as row 0.

For this particular example, it should return `2009q4`, which is the index of that particular row.

If somebody can show me a way to do common tasks like count the number of consecutive occurrences of a given value, detect a value change, get a particular positioned value after a value change etc. for this type of data (which may not required for this problem, but can be useful for future problems), I shall be really grateful.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934399/identifying-consecutive-occurrences-of-a-value) perhaps help?