# How to check each value consecutive same for 5 rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframe one df1 column 'A' values are same for 5 rows and then change and again same for next five rows,   df2 column 'A' values are random no consecutive same value.

i want to use np.where () to give flag if df1 condition detected flag==1 and when df2 condition is detected flag==0

here need to find a way to detect flag 1 when consecutive values detected and detect flag 0 when consecutive values not detected in dataframe.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,8,8,8,8,8,15,15,15]})-------> flag==1
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87]})-----flag==0
```

Comment: `any(np.diff(df1.A.values)==0)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37934721/3620725

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying consecutive occurrences of a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934399/identifying-consecutive-occurrences-of-a-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and check for equality and [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then use [`GroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) with [`pd.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and finally use [`pd.Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html)

```
g = df1['A'].ne(df1['A'].shift()).cumsum()
flag = df1.groupby(g).size().eq(5).any()# if you want consider consecutive elements
# True                                  # greater than equal to 5 replace `.eq` with `.ge`

g1 = df2['A'].ne(df2['A'].shift()).cumsum()
flag2 = df2.groupby(g1).size().eq(5).any()
# False
```