# Find how many consecutive occasions of a column in pandas dataframe with groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                    'col_a': [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1],
                    'col_b': [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]})
```

I would like to create 2 columns:

- col_a_consequent: `1` if `col_a` has `n` consequent occurrences of `1`s **by** `id`
- col_c: `1` if **after** `2` consequent occurrences of `1`s at `col_a` there is `1` at `col_b`

The output dataframe looks like this:
for `n=3`

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                        'col_a': [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1],
                        'col_b': [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
                        'col_a_consequent': [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
                        'col_c': [1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]})
```

For `col_a_consequent` according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934399/identifying-consecutive-occurrences-of-a-value-in-a-column-of-a-pandas-dataframe) I can obtain what I want

```
n = 3

foo_tmp = foo.query('id == 2')

(foo_tmp.col_a.groupby((foo_tmp.col_a != foo_tmp.col_a.shift()).\
                  cumsum()).transform('size') * foo_tmp.col_a >= n).astype(int)
```

but I dont know how I can do the same operation with `groupby` for all `id`s

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

For the first you could use:

```
N = 3
foo['col_a_consequent'] = (foo
                           .groupby(['id', foo['col_a'].ne(foo['col_a'].shift()).cumsum()])
                           ['col_a'].transform('size').ge(N).astype(int)
                          )
```

output:

```
   id  col_a  col_b  col_a_consequent2  col_a_consequent3
0   1      1      0                  1                  0
1   1      1      1                  1                  0
2   1      0      1                  0                  0
3   1      1      0                  0                  0
4   1      0      0                  0                  0
5   2      1      0                  1                  1
6   2      1      1                  1                  1
7   2      1      1                  1                  1
8   2      0      1                  0                  0
9   2      1      0                  0                  0
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work for `N=3`, but it does not work as expected for `N=2`. For `N=2` the `col_a_consequent` column should have values `[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]` whereas your solution gives as output `[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1]`

Comment: @quant you're right, I updated the answer ;)